# Defining Resources.JS

Tags: javascript

Here is a resources file I'm working on. This one is working properly, but eventually CAR,BUS and AIRPLANE will be used in multiple variables.

```
TRANSPORT =
    {
        name        :   'Transport',
        size        :   3,        
        CAR         :
                    {
                        titles      :   ['Small Car'],        
                        coValues    :   [0.1751],
                        size        :   1
                    },
        BUS         :
                    {
                        titles      :   ['Regular'],        
                        coValues    :   [0.2751],
                        size        :   1  
                    },

        AIRPLANE    :
                    {
                        titles      :   ['Boeing'],        
                        coValues    :   [1.11],
                        size        :   1
                    }   
    };
```

If I were to have this .js

```
CAR :
     {
          titles        :   ['Small Car'],        
          coValues  :   [0.1751],
          size      :   1
     },    
TRANSPORT =
        {
            name        :   'Transport',
            size        :   3,                     

            BUS         :
                        {
                            titles      :   ['Regular'],        
                            coValues    :   [0.2751],
                            size        :   1  
                        },

            AIRPLANE    :
                        {
                            titles      :   ['Boeing'],        
                            coValues    :   [1.11],
                            size        :   1
                        }   
        };
```

How would I include a single CAR object in my Transport object. I really don't know how I'm supposed to call it.

Plus, how would I make the CAR object private so it could not be accessed directly outside of this file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include an object as member of another object this way:

```
TRANSPORT.CAR = {...};
```

or

```
TRANSPORT['CAR'] = {...};
```

When you run the code, the TRANSPORT-Object has got another Key (CAR) that references on another Object.

but I suggest that you define a function which creates an object for you because CAR, BUS and AIRPLANE are structured alike and have got same key-names:

```
function createTransportObject(title,value,size){
   return {
      titles : title,        
      coValues  : value,
      size : size
   };

}
```

then you can do this:

```
var TRANSPORT = {};
TRANSPORT.name = 'Transport';
TRANSPORT.size = 3;

TRANSPORT.CAR = createTransportObject('car',[0.1751],1);
TRANSPORT.BUS = createTransportObject(...);
TRANSPORT['AIRPLANE'] = createTransportObject(...);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I dont understand the KEYNAME thing and function need to bypass the problem?  
Plus, It's a reference/constant resource, so I don't need to have Constructor for those, well I don't think I do .

Comment: I actually defined a function so that you do not have to write objects manually over and over again that are built alike. When you call createTransportObject it returns a reference of an object too like you define it manually, because an object is an object and it is passed or returned as reference: call by reference (c++).

Comment: Im kind of dumb of not having seen at first look what you had done :O Thank you for showing me constructors XD